# wp_enqueue_script add integrity parameter

Tags: functions, wp-enqueue-script

I'm **adding fontawesome** script to my site, and I didn't found a proper way to add the fontawesome's integrity parameter (`integrity="sha384-DJ25uNYET2XCl5ZF++U8eNxPWqcKohUUBUpKGlNLMchM7q4Wjg2CUpjHLaL8yYPH"`).

There's a way to do this? Or wordpress doesn't have a current support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to generate your own tag after the script is enqueued. Below, it's looking for the `fontawesome` handle (the one you're using to enqueue the script) before returning the custom tag.

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'my_scripts_modifier', 10, 3 );
function my_scripts_modifier( $tag, $handle, $src ) {
    if ( 'fontawesome' === $handle ) {
        return '<script src="' . $src . '" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha384-DJ25uNYET2XCl5ZF++U8eNxPWqcKohUUBUpKGlNLMchM7q4Wjg2CUpjHLaL8yYPH"></script>' . "\n";
    }
    return $tag;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this hook